# Regular expression C# : check file name containing date and underscores

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check the syntax of a file name in order to treat it and exclude files that don't match the expression.

The file names must be as follows:

> (2 caracters letter or number)_(some caracters letters and numbers)__(YYYY-MM-dd-HH-SS-MM).csv
>
> The last part is a date
> In the middle we have two underscores

Can you help me for this request ? I'm not familiar at all with the regex and the few tests I made were not good.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck? Any patterns you've tried already?

Comment: Are the multiple `(` and `)` present in the actual filenames, or are they only used to illustrate the different filename parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the RegEx suited to your request if the String contains only the filename

```
^.{2}_.+__\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){5}.csv$
```

And this if you want to capture it from a longer String for example

```
(.{2}_.+__\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){5}.csv)
```

If you are having difficulties to create a RegEx i can recommend you to take a look at [RegExr](https://regexr.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I have created some sample. please find below it will work for you also you can modify as per your requirement.

**For example** : `(22)-(ww)-(aa).csv`

```
^[(\[][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[)\]]+(-[(\[][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[)\]]+)+(-[(\[][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[)\]]+.csv)$
```

**For example** : `(22)_(ww)_(01-12-2018 19:20).csv`

```
^[(\[][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[)\]]+(_[(\[][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[)\]]+)+(_[(\[]([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])-\d\d\d\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9][)\]]+.csv)$
```

**For example**: `(22)_(ww)_(1999-12-31-23-59-59).csv`

```
^[(\[][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[)\]]+(_[(\[][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[)\]]+)+(_[(\[]19\d{2}(-|\/)((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(-|\/)((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))(-)(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3]))-([0-5][0-9])-([0-5][0-9])[)\]]+.csv)$
```

I recommend you to refer this URL [Click Here](http://regexlib.com/%28X%281%29A%28FrZCqObYBwvHxnGScvAaavvtBI4jl10u3ZBd2doUNx0NvNkZpMhgDWJFHMHVvo60jDMEowl5qZObXyDnar82BYGxjEcr2SGkIBqcRaZD9LO23a2k18k47l7L7BJb6NfnmkpKUuZgpceArhc3JeIea2dk_scVctLNQ5eymv_jLIp33w-qJYAsKOXByZy0-R_Z0%29%29/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) it will be helpful for learning as well as you can find more example. Thanks